# How to create polygons from unclosed polylines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, polygon-creation, snapping

I have a layer of driveway that is in polylines *unclosed* . They are just two parallel lines outlining the width of the driveway. Then again, there is a gap (sidewalk layer) and driveway continues until it touches the road.
So my question is how to extend the line? and how to close all those lines to form a polygon?

I also have a lot boundary that has a unique ID. So I can summarize the lines that fall within the same boundary ID. But I am encountering the problem to connect the lines and make it a polygon layer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

there are different tools to close polylines automatically. The first that I would suggest in your case is "[extend](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000004000000.htm)". If it is not enough, you can also use "[integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000)", but this could move some vertices that you don't want to move, therefore I always use it on a copy of my data. If your lines are to close there is a risk that they merge.

Another approach consists in building a convex hull (minimum bounding geometry) around lines with the same ID (use dissolve tool): this could be helpful to connect the ends. Alternatively, you can build buffer with square end around your lines.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried integrate. Like you said it is kinda risky to use it. It works for some of the lines only. In some cases it gives a V-shaped end. I will try extend tool later. I suppose I need to filter out only the portions that intersect with the lot and extend them, correct?

Comment: I like the convex hull idea!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one, single driveway, then turn on [editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_editing/01m500000003000000/) and just draw the remaining lines.  After that use the [line to polygon tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000).

Comment: The study area is about 20km2. I wanted to avoid the manual digitization; so , editing is not a good choice in this case.